# Getopt not grabbing and storing my input in C

Tags: c, pointers, printf, getopt

This is my first post on this site so please forgive any formatting errors.
I am coding a small program to get simple information from a file like amount of words, sorting it etc. However I started simply by using getopt since I want to use the command line to parse my commands. This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int value = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    extern char *optarg;
    extern int optind;
    int c, err = 0;
    int cflag = 0, sflag = 0, fflag = 0;
    char *substring;

    // usage from instructions in case of error
    static char usage[] = "usage: mywords [-cs] [-f substring] filename";  

    // only f flag requires additional input
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "csf:")) != -1)
        switch (c) {
            case 'c':
                cflag = 1;
                break;

            case 's':
                sflag = 1;
                break;

            case 'f':
                fflag = 1;
                printf("Before assigning to substring\n");
                substring = optarg;
                printf("After\n");
                break;

            case '?':
                err = 1;
                break;
        }

    if (fflag = 1) {
        printf("%c ", &substring);
    }
}
```

I will then input something like this to the command line after I run my makefile (which runs successfully with no errors):

```
    mywords -f test
```

and ideally the output would be

```
    test
```

The printf statements I have in the fflag are simple test prints to see if I was even reaching there. Thank you for your help in advance.

**EDIT**

It was fixed. David Collins had the right answer. Thank you so much everyone

Comment: Looks like you used `=` instead of `==` when testing for equality. I think you probably mean `if (fflag == 1)`.

Comment: You shouldn't need, or include, the `extern char *optarg;` and `extern int optind;` declarations.  The `<stdlib.h>` should declare them if you compile with POSIX extensions enabled.  If you've suppressed POSIX, then you need to declare `getopt()` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have noticed three issues in you code. (There may be other small issues but addressing the following should get you up and running I think.)

### Testing for equality

You should use `if (fflag == 1)` instead of `if (fflag = 1)`.

### Pointer de-referencing

If you want to retrieve the value of the character pointed to by `substring`, you would use `*substring` instead of `&substring`.

But you probably don't want to do this. See below.

### `printf()` format specifiers

When printing a string / character array, use the `%s` specifier instead of `%c`. (`%c` is for single characters). So you should have

```
if (fflag == 1) {
    printf("%s ", substring);
}
```

Or - more simply - just

```
if (fflag) {
    puts(substring)
}
```

since any non-zero value evaluates to true in C (and you initialize `fflag` to zero at the start of your program).

Comment: Note that if 'substring' points at `"abbc"`, the output of `printf("%s ", substring)` is `"abbc "` but the output of `puts(substring)` is `"abbc\n"`, which is significantly different.  On the whole, it is better — the output should be terminated with a new line; but it is different and in general, that would matter.

Comment: Hello thank you for your help. It is now printing after I fixed my errors. I still have one question. When I would change from %c to %s but still kept the * next to substring (so i had printf("%s ", *substring) it said segmentation fault. Do you know why?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Valid point, thanks - the OP may have omitted the newline character for a reason that isn't apparent from his code.
I will try to update the answer later if time permits (or feel free to edit yourself if you wish.)

Comment: @Kirishimas: when using the `%s` specifier, the argument is expected to be a "a pointer to an array of character type (pointer to a string)" (quote from `printf()` manual). If you use `*substring` then you are passing the _value_ at the address of `substring` instead of the address. `printf()` will try to read from an invalid address - hence the segmentation fault.